Images at the top are fine but then become completely gray
I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with this piece of code and I swear I have checked other people's code in different posts, and it seems this is logically identical. I am sure there's something very obvious I'm missing, but any help would be much appreciated.
In terms of the issue, the code finds the images just fine and starts recovering them but then ends up like this:

Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int buffer_size = 512;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Correct Usage: ./recover image.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];

    FILE *infile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int image_number = 0;
    int is_image = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int file_name_size = 8;
    unsigned char buffer[buffer_size];
    char outfile_name[file_name_size];
    FILE *outfile = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    while (fread(&buffer, buffer_size, 1, infile) == 1)
    {
        if ((buffer[0] == 0xff) & (buffer[1] == 0xd8) & (buffer[2] = 0xff))
        {
            uint8_t fourth_byte = buffer[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                fourth_byte = fourth_byte >> 1;
            }
            if (fourth_byte == 0x0E)
            {
                is_image = 1;
            }

            if (is_image == 1)
            {
                if (first != 1)
                {
                    first = 1;
                }else fclose(outfile);
                sprintf(outfile_name, "%03d.jpg", image_number);
                outfile = fopen(outfile_name, "w");
                image_number++;
                is_image = 0;
            }
        }

        if (first == 1)
        {
            fwrite(&buffer, buffer_size, 1, outfile);
        }
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}

I tried to fix the fread and fwrite function thinking it must have been something to do with them, but no matter what I tried the issue remained.

Did you verify that other people's code produces correct results and/or this affects all images? Maybe the file itself is just broken.

Think carefully about your logic.  You are reading 512 byte blocks of data. Your logic currently flows if (jpeg header) { do stuff } if (first == 1) { write } What do you do with all the blocks that are NOT a header block and NOT the first? Shouldn't it be read then if (jpeg header) { close current, open new } and if (file open) { write }. Then close both files after exiting the loop?

Also don't you mean && for the joining of your header comparisons? & is a bitwise AND of the adjacent parts. The only part where you can use a bitwise & is computing buffer[3] instead of shifting.

Also, if you are just starting C, save yourself untold amounts of time and frustration and visit How to debug small programs. Debugging is as much a part of programming as learning the syntax. One of the most powerful tools described in the article is the "Rubber Duck". Never underestimate the power of the duck.

Better open up file as binary by FILE* infile = fopen(filename, "rb");

@ImanAbdollahzadeh - for Linux and other POSIX conforming systems, the 'b' is provided for compatibility purposes only and is simply ignored. However, non-POSIX conforming systems (embedded or otherwise) may treat text and binary files differently. So it never hurts to include it, but chances are it will simply be ignored. See man 3 fopen

Patrick -- did you find an answer to your question? If so, drop a comment or close this question. If you need further help, edit your question (do not delete or change the original question), and add current information about where you are stuck and we are happy to help further. Hopefully, this wasn't a drive-by and drop-off, hoping to swing by and pickup an answer later. That's not really how StackOverflow is supposed to work.

Yes I did David, your answer regarding the difference between & and && worked! Thank you for your help and improving my understanding. Sorry, I wasn't sure how to accept that as an answer but I see it's just a comment so that doesn't allow me to accept it.
